# What is a name of a critical point?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, terminology, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

Imagine a critical line separating two thermodynamic phases. There is a point on this line splitting the line into two pieces such that on one piece the transition between the two phases is 1st order, on the other piece the phase transition is the 2nd order (continuous transition). Is there a special name for a point like this?

Comment: Besides ‘critical point’?

Comment: There are various types of 'points' on a phase diagram: bicritical, tricritical, tetracritical... Is there a name for a point described in my post

Comment: it's just tricritical it sounds like?